# Sort rows by row value (top to bottom)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There is lotto draw (5 numbers) on each row. I have formula which calculates the most frequient numbers with their number of draws. Is it possible in end result to sort same number of draws results by row value. This means that if number is drawn on top rows will have grater value than those on bottom rows. Considering number of row to be a value. How is that possible?

Formula used:

```
=LET(flatten, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,A1:F27),,";"), numUq, UNIQUE(flatten), matches, XMATCH(flatten,numUq),SORT(HSTACK(numUq, DROP(FREQUENCY(matches, UNIQUE(matches)),-1)),2,-1))
```

In the example screenshot number 35 and number 13 have equal draws count, but 13 should be before 35.

[image]

Data:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 35 | 31 | 13 | 37 | 10 |
| 43 | 47 | 36 | 13 | 6 | 19 |
| 6 | 12 | 6 | 35 | 14 | 1 |
| 43 | 24 | 45 | 7 | 21 | 16 |
| 37 | 39 | 44 | 24 | 12 | 40 |
| 39 | 8 | 34 | 28 | 49 | 46 |
| 27 | 44 | 15 | 46 | 45 | 12 |
| 22 | 0 | 10 | 5 | 28 | 28 |
| 4 | 7 | 23 | 6 | 44 | 41 |
| 30 | 22 | 47 | 13 | 29 | 29 |
| 37 | 9 | 26 | 44 | 39 | 10 |
| 30 | 17 | 21 | 20 | 41 | 22 |
| 43 | 35 | 0 | 22 | 13 | 9 |
| 14 | 22 | 42 | 20 | 32 | 21 |
| 13 | 38 | 48 | 6 | 14 | 2 |
| 11 | 47 | 20 | 20 | 23 | 6 |
| 22 | 26 | 1 | 25 | 45 | 31 |
| 27 | 39 | 6 | 44 | 3 | 24 |
| 22 | 45 | 34 | 17 | 5 | 13 |
| 16 | 23 | 20 | 7 | 30 | 16 |
| 25 | 21 | 7 | 34 | 1 | 35 |
| 32 | 34 | 1 | 9 | 10 | 32 |
| 23 | 35 | 11 | 3 | 6 | 12 |
| 5 | 30 | 4 | 20 | 33 | 15 |
| 26 | 10 | 8 | 28 | 16 | 11 |
| 21 | 14 | 3 | 38 | 10 | 42 |
| 16 | 3 | 26 | 48 | 30 | 28 |

[Link to file](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=C82EDC8661C37156!964&ithint=file%2Cxlsx&authkey=!AAnL9UEzKxJm2QQ)

Comment: `Sort(formula,{2,1},{-1,1})` setting the sort conditions in array, makes it sort column 2 at first, in order -1 then column 1 in order 1

Comment: @P.b I don't see any relation to the question

Comment: In other words: `=LET(flatten, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,A1:F27),,";"), numUq, UNIQUE(flatten), matches, XMATCH(flatten,numUq),SORT(HSTACK(numUq, DROP(FREQUENCY(matches, UNIQUE(matches)),-1)),{2,1},{-1,1}))`

Comment: @IntoTheDeep do you want to order by draws (descending) and by number ascending as a second criteria? If that is the case the answer provided in the comment by P.b is the expected result, if that is not the case, please clarify it in your question or better provide the expected output. Thanks

Comment: The average row number  of 35 in the Lotto draws on the left is about 12 and the average row number of 13 is 9. Is that the reason why 13 should come first? (they're ordered within each group by first appearance row-wise at the moment aren't they which is why 35 comes before 13)

Comment: Yes, the most recent draw (rows at te top - 1, 2 etc.) the more on top should be number (if same number of draws). @TomSharpe - yes, this is the reason. DavidLeal - order by most occurunces AND the most recent occurunces. Thanks

Comment: @TomSharpe This is exactly my target

Comment: OK can you put the data into a form we can copy & paste plz (i.e. text)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is on a bit of the data. Here I have added a third column based on the average row of each unique number and sorted first on frequency then on row average:

```
=LET(range,A1:F3,uniques,UNIQUE(TOCOL(range)),rows,SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),
avrow,BYROW(uniques,LAMBDA(uniq,SUM((range=uniq)*rows/SUM(--(range=uniq))))),
freq,DROP(FREQUENCY(range,uniques),-1),
SORTBY(HSTACK(uniques,freq,avrow),freq,-1,avrow,1))
```

[image]

Can 6 really occur twice in the same draw? Maybe not, but it doesn't affect the answer.

**EDIT**

Here is a version based on your original formula:

```
=LET(range,A1:F27,
flatten, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,A1:F27),,";"),
numUq, UNIQUE(flatten),
rows,SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),
matches, XMATCH(flatten,numUq),
avrow,BYROW(numUq,LAMBDA(numUq,SUM((range=--numUq)*rows/SUM(--(range=--numUq))))),
freq,DROP(FREQUENCY(matches, UNIQUE(matches)),-1),
SORTBY(HSTACK(numUq,freq,avrow),freq,-1,avrow,1))
```

**Full Dataset**

[image]

The sorting is based on number of appearances and average row, but you could use other measures like row of first appearance if you wanted to.

Comment: Sure, Is it possible to edit my formula instead creating a new (different one)? https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=C82EDC8661C37156!964&ithint=file%2cxlsx&authkey=!AAnL9UEzKxJm2QQ

Comment: I guess so, although unless you said that in your original question people are going to answer in their own peculiar way. For example using tocol (equivalent of flatten) and not using xmatch in my case.

Comment: OK I have posted another version keeping as close as possible to your original formula. TBH it was not an enjoyable experience because in using textsplit/textjoin you converted all your numbers into text and it messed everything up. I couldn't see why you used xmatch until now - it was to convert them all back into numbers.

Comment: They appear to be working in your sheet?

Comment: Nice approach, but with given data it results in false sorting for 44, 35  and 21 for instance (edited the question to have usable data). Each have frequency of 5 and 35 is the only value that appears in the first row, therefore should be listed first, followed by 21; then 44.

Comment: I thought about summing up the row^10 where the value occurs, but that doesn't give accurate results either:

Comment: `=LET(data,A2:F28,
columncount,COLUMNS(data),
flatten, --TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,data),,";"),
rowvalue,(columncount-INT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(data),,columncount)/columncount))^10,
numUq, UNIQUE(flatten),
matches, XMATCH(flatten,numUq),
freq,DROP(FREQUENCY(matches,UNIQUE(matches)),-1),
sortcolumn,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(flatten)=numUq),rowvalue),
preresult,SORT(HSTACK(numUq,freq,sortcolumn),{2,3},{-1,1}),
INDEX(preresult,SEQUENCE(ROWS(preresult)),SEQUENCE(1,2)))
`

Comment: I had the same challenge with non numeric `flatten` values, which is why I added `--` prior to it.

Comment: I managed to workaround the TEXTSPLIT/TEXTJOIN problem of converting to text by using TOCOL (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Different approach:

```
=LET(data,A1:F27,
          a,TOCOL(data),
          b,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(a)=a),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(a),,1,0)),
          c,TOCOL(IF(ISNUMBER(data),MAX(ROW(data)+1)-ROW(data)^99)),
          d,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(a)=a),c),
          s,SORTBY(HSTACK(a,b),b,-1,d,1),
UNIQUE(s))
```

[image]

`a` "flattens" the data using `TOCOL`.
`b` creates a "countif" of the drawn values in `a` using `MMULT`.
`c` returns the maximum row value of the data + 1 minus the row value of each value found ^99.
*^99 because I want the number to be higher if it would be found in the first row only versus if it was found in each row except the first.*
`d` returns a "sumif" of the calculated row values of `c` against the values of `a`.

We than only need `a` and `b` for the list using `HSTACK`, but we need them sorted by the count `b` descending and sorted by the sumif `d` ascending using `SORTBY`.

This will sort it as you illustrated it.
If it's a tie (36 and 19 in the data) it will show the first in row first.